# How to parse html string with xpath

Tags: html, go, xpath

How to select an image (or another HTML tag) with XPath in Go?

```
resp, _ := http.Get(url)
bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

s := string(bytes))
```

how to parse `s` with XPath?

like this code:

```
list := libxxxx.Find(s, "//a@href")
```

I get HTML code with `http.Get` but when I want to parse it I have a problem.

Comment: share your full code what your html contains and what are you want to get after parsing the html.

Comment: you can also check out this [link](https://play.golang.org/p/O4_y4AMYJR)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use  [htmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/htmlquery):

```
doc, err := htmlquery.LoadURL("http://example.com/")
```

or use string:

```
s := `<html>....</html>`
doc, err := htmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
```

then find everything:

```
list := htmlquery.Find(doc, "//a")
list := range htmlquery.Find(doc, "//a[@href]")
```